# How to stop camera.capture_continuous?

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, picamera

i try to set up a timelapse with PiCamera and Schedule.

I want to start my Timelapse at 06:00 in the morning and stop at 21:00.

I can start the code without a problem, but every try to stop the image capture, did not work.

Here is the code so far.

```
from picamera import PiCamera
from time import sleep
import schedule
import time

def Foto():
    camera = PiCamera()
    camera.rotation = (180)
    camera.resolution = (1920, 1080)
    camera.start_preview()
    sleep(2)
    for filename in camera.capture_continuous('img{counter:03d}.jpg'):
        print('Captured %s' % filename)
        sleep(10) # wait 5 Sek
    
schedule.every().day.at("19:51:20").do(Foto)

while True:
    schedule.run_pending()
    time.sleep(1)
```

Ive tried to stop the code with `camera.close` and `break` but it did not worked.

In the documentation the wirte:

> With this method, the camera captures images continually until you
> tell it to stop

But how do i do this?

Here is the documentation:

https://picamera.readthedocs.io/en/release-1.13/recipes1.html#capturing-timelapse-sequences

Comment: I usually just break out of the loop by setting a variable from another thread and using `break`. How are you trying to trigger the exit from the loop? Are you scheduling another task at 21:00 to stop the capture?

Comment: No, i just want to capture till 21.00

Comment: The problem is that scheduler is designed to execute a short lived task at certain intervals. Because Foto never returns you're no longer in the scheduler loop so you can't use the scheduler to terminate your Foto loop. You have a couple of choices. 1. Use the scheduler to take a single frame every n seconds between 06:00 and 21:00 (i.e. use capture instead of capture_continuous) or 2. Abandon the scheduler and work out yourself whether you're within the start and stop times, breaking out of the capture loop after 21:00, and then waiting until 6:00 to start capturing again.